# Prevent login screen on screen rotation android

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-windowmanager

I have an application in which a login screen shows up whenever an activity goes to onPause state. Generally, when screen orientation changes, the activity goes to onPause state, so I somehow prevented login screen when device is rotated. See the code below,

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    WindowManager mWindowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    mOrientation = mDisplay.getRotation();

    if(mOrientation == 1 || mOrientation == 2 || mOrientation == 3 || mOrientation == 0)
    {
        inApp = true;
    }
    if (!inApp) {

        SavedState.setState(this, "HomeActivity");

        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

But the problem is when i press home button and comes back to the application, the login screen is not showing up instead it is directly resuming to the activity, because `mDisplay.getRotation()` reads the screen current orientation and `if` condition always becomes true.

To put it simple and clear, I need the login screen to be shown when the user presses Home button or switches to other application but not when the screen is rotated.

Any kind of suggestion or example is much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should work -- you might have to flesh it out a bit...

```
class MyActivity... {
    private boolean loggedIn = false;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle data ) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState( data );
    data.putBoolean( "loggedIn", loggedIn );
}

@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    isLoggedIn = false; // user pressed home
}

@Override 
protected void onCreate( Bundle data ) {
    isLoggedIn = data.getBoolean( "loggedIn", false );
    ....
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if( !isLoggedIn ) {
        /// Log in...
    }
}
```

This pattern uses/restores the state of the activity using the preferred method, and as a bonus, logs out the user if the Home button is pressed (or the user activity decides to move to a different app). Note that phone-calls should not log the user out here -- which in most cases is the desired behavior.

Make sure you remove the `android:configChanges` garbage that someone else recommended.

Answer (score -2):

By default, Android will actually destroy and restart your activity on rotation.  This causes `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`, `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()` to be called.  The best way to avoid problems like this is to tell Android not to do that.  In the manifest add `android:configChange="orientation"` to your Activity.  It will prevent the destruction, and call a function on rotation instead.  It will still correctly redraw your screen in almost all cases.

Comment: On api 13 and above you must also include screenSize in the configChange list.

Comment: I tried with this tag `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest file, but its still the same. What do you meann by `It will prevent the destruction, and call a function on rotation instead` in your answer???

Comment: That is actually not "the best way" to avoid that. The preferred way is to implement onSaveInstanceState and evaluate the `Bundle` passed into onCreate.

Comment: @323go But when the screen is rotated it goes to onPause state rite?? and to prevent that I added 'android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"'. So is it that I have to implement `onSaveInstanceState` to prevent activity going to onPause state??

Comment: @SrujanSimha, I provided an answer with the recommended pattern. Telling Android that you handle configuration changes through the manifest is discouraged (see Activity documentation), and should only be done if indeed you are handling configuration changes.

Comment: I agree.  `android:configChange="orientation"` is thrown around like confetti and causes many problems since less experienced devs don't understand all of the consequences. The bigger problem is that devs don't learn how to save state and manage the life cycle.  The Play Store is littered with apps that crash when the user changes language (and their activity is destroyed) or slide out a physical keyboard, or the phone rings or any number of other reasons why their activity might be destroyed.  SO should be discouraging the use of android:configChanges.

Comment: @323go Yes, it is the best way to avoid the problem.  The decision to stop, delete, and restart your activity on rotation is a design mistke in Android.  It was a stupid decision that's burned in to deeply to get rid of.  That's why they provide not just one, but two ways to get around it.  Of the two saveInstanceState is idiotic-  it's an utter hack.  You have to create a complex object to store all your state that has no other value and continually parse in and out of it.  That's just stupid.  No, the correct answer is to turn off bad system behavior that complicates apps with no benefit.

Comment: Nope, I understand OOP quite well.  Please tell me how that architecture decision has anything to do with OOP?  If anything its totally against standard patterns, as an Activity is a Controller, not a View.  Here's the facts-  Android made a bad decision that provides little to no benefits to the programmer while inflicting significant costs on a large number of programmers.  Name even 1 benefit of destructing the activity on rotation.  And no, automatic redrawing is not a benefit-  you can do that (and Android does do it) regardless.

Comment: @GabeSechan, you have made it utterly clear that you don't understand nor agree with sound OOP design decisions that were made when Android was developed. A comment thread on SO is not a good place for a basic OOP tutorial, so I leave it up to you to find something when you have a day or two between your weekly app releases.

Comment: Ok, you can't give any reasons.  I accept your admission that you're wrong.